# Is my table structure for a simple website's index page efficient?

Tags: mysql, database

Is my mysql table structured efficiently? I'm making a simple home-page(index-page) which have three section :

```
 Top section consisted of three part :
A Background image (string, only image-path is being saved here)
A main title (string)
A short explanation of the main title (string).
```

The middle section has three parts also :

```
Left-part : Welcome message (string)
Middle part : 'Where' information (string)
Right part : ' When ' information (string)
```

The footer, also has three part :

```
Left-part : some content (string)
Middle-part : link to our affiliate/partner's website . Will have three column for the ID(integer), displayed name (String) and the actual link (string) 
RIght-part : our main office address (string) and below that, a social media icons as links to our social media.
```

I'm thinking of placing the entire top and middle section, and also the footer-left part into a single table (let's name it `Table 1`), as they have only have a single row (will always returned a single row), and do not have any relationship. I don't think I need an ID for this table, do I?

For the footer section, I think I need to separate them into two tables for the middle-part and right-part which returned several rows as their result. (Because they're links).

So `Table 2` is the footer section-middle part :

```
ID (integer)
Displayed name (string)
The actual link (string)
```

For my footer-right section which consisted of an address and a social media link, should I put the "address" column into `Table 1` which have only a single row in their content? So that the social media table (let's name it `table 3` purely consisted of the `id` and `social media links`.

Is my table structure eficient? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're designing a Content Management System. You should probably just use one that already exists, like WordPress.

Comment: Anyway, [so] is not an appropriate place for general design discussions. You need to ask specific questions about actual code, and there should be an objectively correct answer rather than opinions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it's a CMS but also have some other features.I've covered the other features, but still have doubt for the index-page structure.